# How to get parent Window in FXML Controller?

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

For example, I want open a DirectoryChooser when clicking on the button:

```
<VBox fx:controller="com.foo.MyController"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <children>
        <Button text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction"/>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

And the Controller class:

```
package com.foo;

public class MyController {
    public void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        DirectoryChooser dc = new DirectoryChooser();
        File folder = dc.showDialog(null);//I want to put the WIndows here.
    }
}
```

I want to put the main Window to the *ShowDialog* so that it will be blocked but how can I access it?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can ask any node for the `Scene` and then call `Scene#getWindow()`.

```java
((Node) event.getTarget()).getScene().getWindow()
```

From [@osvein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1981338/osvein) if this is a handler for a `MenuItem` it should be:

```java
((MenuItem) event.getTarget()).getParentPopup().getOwnerWindow()
```

Comment: Can this be done for a MenuItem? Your code gives this error for me: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.control.MenuItem cannot be cast to javafx.scene.Node`

Comment: @zygimantus `((MenuItem)event.getTarget()).getParentPopup().getOwnerWindow()`