# JavaFX2 Scenes in separated classes

Tags: java, javafx

Is there a way to keep my scenes in separate Java files in a JavaFx application?
I tried something like this:

```
public class MyApp extends Application 
  {

    private void init(Stage primaryStage) 
    {
        Group root = new Group();
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        Login login = new Login(root, primaryStage); // from another file
        primaryStage.setScene(login);
    }
```

I have to close my login scene after authentication and load another scene from another file, so I'm passing the `primaryStage` as a parameter for my `login Scene` to use `stage.close()`

*Is there a better way for doing that?*

My Login scene file

```
public class Login extends Scene 
 {
    public Login(Group root, final Stage stage) 
     {
        super(root, 265, 390, Color.web("EBE8E3"));
```

Is there another way to reference the current scene stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to pass the `stage` as a parameter. The stage is always available from the nodes of the current scene !

```
scene.getWindow()
```

This returns the current stage/window of the scene !

**Javadocs :** http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#getWindow%28%29

**Example :** [How to get parent Window in FXML Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585590/how-to-get-parent-window-in-fxml-controller)

http://blog.crisp.se/2012/08/29/perlundholm/window-scene-and-node-coordinates-in-javafx

Comment: Thank you. I switched from stage.close(); to window.hide();. It's working better now.